# Are all services singleton in osgi?

Tags: singleton, osgi

I have this basic doubt related to osgi. Are all services singleton in osgi? How exactly services different from components? And if services are not singleton, why do we use @reference instead of creating new instance?

Answer (score 2):

Every declarative services component will create at least one OSGi service for the component. For some components you can have more than one configuration. In this case you will have one component and service instance per config.

@Reference will give you the best matching service for the interface or class you inject into.

DS components create services but you can also create OSGi services in other ways. For example using the OSGi API or blueprint.